# Errors in a false complex proof

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs

This proof tries to show that

$ \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{C} $

$Let  z \in \mathbb{C}, \exists r \in \mathbb{R}^{+}, \theta \in [0,2\pi]:z=re^{i\theta}$
    $\\z=re^{i\theta\frac{2\pi}{2\pi}} = r(e^{2\pi i})^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}}= r(1)^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}}=r
\\so z \in \mathbb{R}
\\\rightarrow\mathbb{C} \subset \mathbb{R}
\\ therefore \mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}$

This proof is clearly false but I can't seem to find any algebraic mistake in it.

Comment: Could you edit the formula with mathjax?

Comment: @DietrichBurde sorry, I only know basic latex.

Comment: I can't really read it, but it seems that you think that $e^{i\theta\frac{2\pi}{2\pi}}=(e^{i\cdot 2\pi})^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}}$. This is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equality $$(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$$ is not true for complex numbers (it is only true *in general* if $a$ is a positive real, and $b,c$ are real), so your proof is false.